# can i get mobile number of iphone from ios 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

Can i get mobile number of iphone using ios sdk. I have found some CTCarrier but i could not get phone number of sim card.

I found some conversation in stack that it is not possible. Is that correct ?

Plz help

Comment: It's not possible due to privacy limitations from Apple.

Comment: Hey bro that blog has asked question in 2008-09 and i clearly mention in my question. dont u read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not access your mobile number from any Apple public API which means you can't get it.

If you are implementing a dialer application I can't see what you would need the own phone number for. It's not like you are going to call yourself?

Comment: I m not developing dialer application bro. Its for another use.

Comment: ok. but for security reasons apple does not provide this type of functionality to get its own phone number. So sorry bro...

Comment: Thanks buddy i know its big security reason.

Comment: ok if you get it then please +1 UP bro... Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

NOT possible, It is a big privacy deal. why do you want? you want to get the phone numbers of all the people who are using your app? Use it for marketing stuff?. sorry no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask user to enter his mobile number but without prompting him or in background its not possible to get the user phone number .....